# AD Query Performance When All AD Members Perform Queries

Tags: database, performance, active-directory

Are there major performance implications when an application that queries/searches AD multiples times a day is installed on ALL AD users in the domain for a company?

My initial thoughts were "no" because AD already queries when a user logs in among other functions and this constitutes a linear time increase. But I wanted to get a general sense of the scope of the performance impact, and if there are likely to be issues - anything I'm overlooking, if such an application is installed at my company (note, I am missing the more important aspects such as server information, but I really just want a general idea in a *typical* environment setup and have provided as much information as I can).

Specs:

- ~500-1000 users on AD domain
- Each user queries AD 5-10 times a day
- The query code for the application looks like:

```
using(var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
    using (var searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(new UserPrincipal(context)))
    {
        UserPrincipal up = new UserPrincipal(context)
        {
            EmailAddress = "emailAddress"
        };
        searcher.QueryFilter = up;
        var results = searcher.FindAll();
    }
}
```

Thank you, and please let me know if there's any crucial information missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `EmailAddress` property translates to the [`mail`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-mail) attribute in AD, which is indexed ("Is Indexed" is "True" in the documentation). So that's a very fast search.

You'll be fine.

Comment: That's good to know! Maybe a silly question (considering it's not hard to add an index), but what's your take on same question but on a non-indexed field?

Comment: It's less efficient, since it would have to test against *every* user account to find matches. But it all depends on your environment. For example, how many DCs you have and how busy the DCs are otherwise. My guess is that you wouldn't notice anything except maybe those queries taking a bit longer at peak times.

Comment: If you're worried about performance, I'd suggest you don't use `PrincipalSearcher`. Instead use [`DirectorySearcher`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher), which is what `PrincipalSearcher` uses in the background anyway. It gives you more control over what's going on. I wrote an article about how to get better performance when talking to AD, if it would help you: [Active Directory: Better performance](https://www.gabescode.com/active-directory/2018/12/15/better-performance-activedirectory.html)